# Why does "malloc(): corrupted top size" error get fixed when I have printf() before/after it?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

Given an absolute path I am trying to get the part that comes after a certain directory. `getTargetPath` function does that and when I compile and run the code below, the code gives me the expected output.

The problem is when I remove the `printf("\n")` before the line with `malloc` in main, I get:

*malloc(): corrupted top size

Aborted (core dumped)*

So when I put a `printf("\n")` before or after the line with `malloc` the code seems to work fine but when I remove it, I get the error above.

My question is, why does this happen? I am not asking for a solution to my problem with the path string. I just want to learn what causes this behavior.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


const char* getTargetPath(const char* source)
{
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while(*source)
    {
        if (*source == '/')
        {
            ++count;
            if (count == 4)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        ++source;
    }

    return source;
}


int main()
{
    const char* backup_path = "/home/ofy/real_2";
    char temp1[] = "/home/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5";
    const char* s1 = temp1;

    const char* s2 = getTargetPath(s1);

    printf("\n");
    char* full_path = (char*)malloc(strlen(backup_path) * sizeof(char));

    strcpy(full_path, backup_path);
    strcat(full_path, s2);

    printf("%s\n", full_path);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there room in your `full_path` for the null-terminator?

Comment: Actually, it's worse than that since you also try to concatenate `s2` to the end of `full_path` and you definitely don't leave room for that.

Comment: @Christian Gibbons I just tried allocating more space for it and it worked, but my question is still why does having a printf solve the problem, or at least hide it?

Comment: @OmerFY: Undefined behavior is undefined. We're not going to figure out the precise implementation of your allocator just to tell you *how* it broke after you misused it. The answer is "Don't misuse it".

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.  It is a futile exercise to reason with it.  It's perfectly within specifications for undefined behavior to cause The Sun to go dark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not allocating enough space for `full_path`:

```
char* full_path = (char*)malloc(strlen(backup_path) * sizeof(char));
```

It needs to be at least as long as `backup_path` **and** `s2`, plus 1 for the terminating null byte, but you only have enough for `backup_path`.  This results in you writing past the end of allocated memory which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

With undefined behavior, you can't predict what your program will do.  It could crash, it could output strange results, or it can appear to work properly.  Also, making a seemingly unrelated code change can change how UB manifests itself.  This is exactly what you saw when you removed the `printf` call.  With the `printf` the program "worked" while without it the program crashed.

To allocate the proper amount of space:

```
char* full_path = (char*)malloc(strlen(backup_path) + strlen(s2) + 1);
```